# Gson deserialization throws a casting error

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to use the Gson library to deserialize a Json object, everything works out to be fine but this one data type and class is giving me errors

E/AndroidRuntime(11573): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to frameWork.DataManager.Token

Sample Json:

```
[{"ID":-1,"Token":"APA91bFQdK7qVJheMBsulWBYYVAan5AwLyMT5cL_BYaoDXxlDGoxabZ0XRnn6osNtmA1KvDOFb3mHkFDpXJ_zxshFSLY0cbt0dMmSZFDCXkDKfha2M_TRMwyB86c38do5Ngje_AOHfasfasfasfafasfascascrvfbdfbdfbfsfafasfasfasfaok","OS":"Android","Application":"Merchant"}]
```

Class object

```
public class Token {

    public int ID;
    public String Token;
    public String OS;
    public String Application;

}
```

Actual Code where result is the Json String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

this.mainScreenActivity.dataStorageManager.deviceToken = gson.fromJson(
        result, new TypeToken<List<Token>>() {
}.getType());
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a

```
new TypeToken<List<Token>>
```

You should be assigning the return value of `Gson#fromJson` to a

```
List<Token>
```

not a

```
Token
```

which

```
this.mainScreenActivity.dataStorageManager.deviceToken
```

seems to be.